# How to get libstdcxx implicit link directory in a portable manner in CMake

Tags: c++, gcc, hyperlink, cmake, libstdc++

The background is our project have to work with different GCC versions (**ABI might not be compatible**) and several versions of GCC are installed in our build server. We use a wrapper project to set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, prepare the environment by `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/path/to/gcclib/` and launch our application within the wrapper script.

Since different flavors of gcc/g++ are used, we want to know if there's an easy way to get the implicit library path that **libstdc++.so** is linked against. For example, one of the GCC tools are installed in */opt/gcc4/gcc4.7/bin/g++* and the libstdc++.so can be found in */opt/gcc4/gcc4.7/lib/* while another GCC variant might be found in */usr/local/bin/g++* and */usr/lib/libstdc++.so*.

Comment: Are you sure you want to differentiate between std libraries, not compilers? Are you using single compiler and different libs?

Comment: @arrowdodger We have different suite of compilers used, distinguished by a flag - in command line parameter things alike. The problem is we need to find out the corresponding link library path according to the **currently used** compiler variant.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you are specifying an absolute path when setting `CMAKE_{C,CXX}_COMPILER` vars. In this case you can use it to obtain library dir:

```
get_filename_component(GCC_PATH ${CMAKE_C_COMPILER} PATH)
#now ${GCC_PATH} contains "/opt/gcc4/gcc4.7/bin", for example
set(LIBSTD_PATH "${GCC_PATH}/../lib")
```

For system compiler you can use an `if` statement:

```
if(GCC_PATH STREQUAL /usr/local/bin)
set(LIBSTD_PATH "/usr/lib")
endif()
```

Comment: This trick do work well for my case, however those `CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER` vars are not specified by code but obtained from `PATH`